# MYSQL: can find but not replace corrupt characters

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I have an odd problem in that I can FIND fields that have the corrupt characters I am looking for, but using REPLACE will affect zero items:

The query below (has corrupt characters after the % that can only been seen in Firefox text fields btw, not Chrome or Safari) WORKS and will return over a thousand records.

```
SELECT * from resource_data where value like '%';
```

BUT the following update query affects ZERO items, despite having the exact same like value.

```
UPDATE resource_data
SET value = REPLACE(value,'%','')
WHERE value like '%';
```

Any ideas?

FYI, here is what the characters look like in Firefox:[image: notice the corrupt characters? That is what I am cutting and pasting into my query after the %]

Comment: You know that `%` is the wildcard operator of `like`?

Comment: of course. As I mentioned above, you can't see the corrupt characters AFTER the %, but they are there.

Comment: Notice me if i wrong, but value like '%'; MATCH any string, even empty ones

Comment: ditto what I said in reply to same comment above, it is NOT EMPTY.

Comment: what do you mean 'corrupt' characters? your where statement match ANY string (that means all your records have 'corrupt' characters)

Comment: The characters are cut and pasted from firefox into my SQL query and return many records, there most assuredly are characters there. I have a screenshot shared in google photos that you can view here: https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOKkFdGHPcFdw33f3xl-C36qmW4czgNcaLuylvl1Iaj52lIDSBZagUH4_ZkppwVOw?key=TVpHcDd4Zm9weFVXMEtYcUNpbHFPZ2NVVTRjbl9n

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- we need to see the `CHARACTER SET` for the column.

Comment: encoding for col is cp1252 West European, collation is latin1_swedish_ci (and encoding for table is latin1). Here is the create table statement: `CREATE TABLE resource_data (
  resource int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  resource_type_field int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  value mediumtext,
  KEY resource (resource)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is hex `1D` in latin1, ...

See if this fetches the rows, corrected:

```
SELECT REPLACE(value, UNHEX('1D'), '')
    FROM resource_data
    WHERE value LIKE CONCAT('%', UNHEX('1D'), '%');
```

If it shows the row(s), then consider doing

```
UPDATE resource_data
    SET value = REPLACE(value, UNHEX('1D'), '');
```

Comment: The SELECT statement worked, but the update statement failed with "Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'UNHEX'"

Comment: OH WAIT...I just cut and pasted your code, and just realized you have an error in your update statement...it should read: `UPDATE resource_data
    SET value = REPLACE(value, UNHEX('1D'), '');` Once I fixed that, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UPDATE resource_data
SET value = REPLACE(value,'%','')
WHERE INSTR(value, '%') > 0
```

Comment: Thanks, but also 0 rows affected. The problem isn't really in the WHERE clause, because even leaving it out completely fails in the same way.